# Android: How to parse JSON Array of Array of objects

Tags: android, arrays, json

Can any body tell me how I parse this type of json in android?

```
[
   [
      {
         "condition_id":"1",
         "condition_name":"Type 1 Diebetics"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "condition_id":"2",
         "condition_name":"Type 2 dypatise"
      }
   ]
]
```

Thanks

**Solved**

Thank you very much `nayoso`
Its worked for me.

```
String jsonString = "[
   [
      {
         "condition_id":"1",
         "condition_name":"Type 1 Diebetics"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "condition_id":"2",
         "condition_name":"Type 2 dypatise"
      }
   ]
]";
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length(),i++) {
   JSONArray childJsonArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
   JSONObject contentJsonObject = childJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
   String conditionID = contentJsonObject.getString('condition_id');
   String conditionName = contentJsonObject.getString('condition_name');
   Log.i("TAG","Index "+i+" condition_id "+conditionID+" condition_name "+conditionName);
}
```

You can do this easily with the org.json library. The whole thing is a JSONArray; at position 0 (use .get(0)) you have another JSONArray; at position 0 of that, you have a JSONObject, which maps keys to values (use .getString()).

Thanks `chiastic-security` also for making me understand.

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) pretty much explains it.

Comment: Thanks for your Response I read it out.

Comment: why given me down vote on that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built in JSONArray and JSONObject classes

```
String jsonString = "[
   [
      {
         "condition_id":"1",
         "condition_name":"Type 1 Diebetics"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "condition_id":"2",
         "condition_name":"Type 2 dypatise"
      }
   ]
]";
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length(),i++) {
   JSONArray childJsonArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
   JSONObject contentJsonObject = childJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
   String conditionID = contentJsonObject.getString('condition_id');
   String conditionName = contentJsonObject.getString('condition_name');
   Log.i("TAG","Index "+i+" condition_id "+conditionID+" condition_name "+conditionName);
}
```

Comment: I am getting this exception org.json.JSONException: Value [{"condition_id":"2","condition_name":"Type 2 dypatise"}] at 1 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: also FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
and Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONArray.<init>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with the `org.json` library. The whole thing is a `JSONArray`; at position 0 (use `.get(0)`) you have another `JSONArray`; at position 0 of that, you have a `JSONObject`, which maps keys to values (use `.getString()`).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String data = ""; //your json data string
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(data);

for(int i = 0;i < jarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray jarry1 = jarray.getJSONArray(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < jarry1.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject jobj = jarry1.getJSONObject(0);
        String ConditionId = jobj.getString("condition_id");
        String ConditionName = jobj.getString("condition_name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray jsonarray=new JSONArray(your_data);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONArray array=jsonarray.getJSONArray(i);
                    for(int j=0;j<array.length();j++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=array.getJSONObject(0);
                        String ConditionId=jsonObject.getString("condition_id");
                        String ConditionName=jsonObject.getString("condition_name");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("Your Data");
      JSONArray tempArray ; 
      net.sf.json.JSONObject tempJson ;
      for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++)
      {
          tempArray =  jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);

          tempJson =  tempArray.getJSONObject(0);

          tempJson.get("condition_id");

          ....data So On
      }
```