# Access Nested JSON Android

Tags: android, json

I want to know **how do I access the values of this JSON in Android:**

```
{
    "dados": [{
        "Id": 3,
        "IdChamado": 3,
        "Chamado": "value",
        "Solicitante": "value",
        "Acao": "",
        "ItemDeCatalogo": "Mobile | Instalação",
        "InicioPrevisto": "06/01/2017 08:11:00",
        "TerminoPrevisto": "06/01/2017 08:22:00"
    }, {
        "Id": 4,
        "IdChamado": 4,
        "Chamado": "value",
        "Solicitante": "value",
        "Acao": "",
        "ItemDeCatalogo": "value",
        "InicioPrevisto": "06/01/2017 08:11:34",
        "TerminoPrevisto": "06/01/2017 08:11:34"
    }],
    "success": true,
    "erroAplicacao": false
}
```

I need to access the values "IdChamado", "chamado", "Solicitante", for example. I've seen nested arrays answers but with jsonObjects having an actual name, like [this](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLwvzbmLXSAhWEgZAKHaINBagQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F30552793%2Fhow-to-access-nested-arrays-in-a-json-object-android&usg=AFQjCNHYbDMEPtndY1fNe4pSZaAFbOez4g&bvm=bv.148441817,d.Y2I) .

PS: I'm sorry I forgot to post my codes:

```
 //Method called when the doInBack is complete
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dados");
            Log.i("***2nd JSON ITSELF***", result);

            for (int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonPart = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    int id = jsonPart.getInt("id");
                    Log.i("***id***", String.valueOf(id));
                    String chamado = jsonPart.getString("Chamado");
                    Log.i("***Chamado***", chamado);
                    String solicitante = jsonPart.getString("solicitante");
                    Log.i("***Solicitante***", solicitante);
                    String itemDeCatalogo = jsonPart.getString("itemDeCatalogo");
                    Log.i("***Item de Catalogo***", itemDeCatalogo);
                }
        }catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//  END CATCH
    }// END POST EXECUTE
```

[SOLVED]: Thank you so much people, you are the reason I like to code (Not be afraid of asking stupid questions). It all worked well with the codes you sent as answer. I thought it would be more complicated. xD

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("dados");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String idChamado = jobject.getString("IdChamado");
                String solicitante = jobject.getString("Solicitante");
                Log.i("**id**", idChamado);
                Log.i("**solicitante**", solicitante);
            }
        }catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//  END CATCH
    }// END POST EXECUTE
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: See what you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117313/android-how-to-parse-json-array-of-array-of-objects
Possible Duplicate.

Comment: What is the issue ur facing ??

Comment: please check my answer @Arthurabreu

Comment: check the three answers

Comment: @ArthurAbreu your code is correct. Now just check how many times your asynctask calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject("your JSON String here");
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("dados");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String IdChamado = jsonobject.getString("IdChamado");    
     String Solicitante = jsonobject.getString("Solicitante"); 
}
```

please try this

Comment: Thanks Sr., it worked, but on a loop. I got all the values repeated some 4 or 5 times. Any obvious reason or maybe something with my code?

Comment: can you please post your editted code? will help you don't worry @ArthurAbreu

Comment: please check where and how many times your asynctask runs in debug mode? @ArthurAbreu

Comment: I feel stupid. My app had  delay to login and I clicked it more than once. There is no loop. I just need to make a loading screen for it. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Happy to help you bro :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 try{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("dados");
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
         JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         String IdChamado = object.getString("IdChamado");
         String Chamado = object.getString("Chamado");
         //rest of the strings..
        }
     }
     catch (JSONException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like Zaki answer but in a loop. I got all the values repeated some 4 or 5 times. Any obvious reason or maybe something with my code?

Comment: @ArthurAbreu did you checked it with log?

Comment: Thanks for the help, the loop was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    for (int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonobject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        int IdChamado = jsonobject.getInt("IdChamado");  //idchamado here  
                        String chamado = jsonobject.getString("Chamado");
                        String solicitante = jsonobject.getString("Solicitante");

                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct keys while opting any data

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
try {
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("dados");
Log.i("***2nd JSON ITSELF***", result);
for (int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("dados");
Log.i("***2nd JSON ITSELF***", result);
for (int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonPart = jArray.optJSONObject(i);
int id = jsonPart.optInt("Id");
Log.i("***id***", String.valueOf(id));
String chamado = jsonPart.optString("Chamado");
Log.i("***Chamado***", chamado);
String solicitante = jsonPart.optString("Solicitante");
Log.i("***Solicitante***", solicitante);
String itemDeCatalogo = jsonPart.optString("ItemDeCatalogo");
Log.i("***Item de Catalogo***", itemDeCatalogo);
}
}catch(JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}//  END CATCH
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for parsing and generating JSON in Android
http://github.com/amirdew/JSON

for your sample:

```
JSON jsonData = new JSON(jsonString);

//access IdChamado of first item:
int IdChamado = jsonData.key("dados").index(0).key("IdChamado").intValue();


//in loop:

JSON dadosList = jsonData.key("dados");

for(int i=0; i<dadosList.count(); i++){
   int IdChamado = dadosList.index(i).key("IdChamado").intValue();
   String Chamado = dadosList.index(i).key("Chamado").stringValue();
}
```