# How do we pass JSONObject as string in getJSONArray();?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to fetch multiple `JSONArray` from an `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response_view); 
for(int x=0; x<jsonObject.length(); x++) {  
 JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Here I have to pass");
}
```

This is my `JSON`,

```
{
    "Mr. VICKRAM SINGH_269": [{
        "status": "P",
        "date": "2017-02-05"
    }, {
        "status": "P",
        "date": "2017-02-06"
    }],
    "Mr. VIVEK KUMAR YADAV_276": [{
        "status": "P",
        "date": "2017-02-05"
    }, {
        "status": "P",
        "date": "2017-02-06"
    }]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42530742/7320259 please check my answer. this question have JSON too

Comment: post your resonse_view JSON so we can help you

Comment: {"Mr. VICKRAM  SINGH_269":[{"status":"P","date":"2017-02-05"},{"status":"P","date":"2017-02-06"}],"Mr. VIVEK KUMAR YADAV_276":[{"status":"P","date":"2017-02-05"},{"status":"P","date":"2017-02-06"}]}

Comment: Data is Dynamic we have to use indexing..but dont Know how we pass

Comment: you need to change your JSON Response. you cant get this data easily

Comment: In your Previous example    
stackoverflow.com/a/42530742/7320259  array name is static but I am having Dynamic array

Comment: In  that example "dados" is the array key so it is easily done

Comment: yes it easily done but my array key is Dynamic that is the problem and i dont know the Specific  name  as it is dynamic

Comment: you have to try chetan answer i think it helps you

Comment: Thanks #chetan I get My Solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse Json like below:

```
try{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonRespondeString);
    Iterator<String> iterator =  json.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
           String key =  iterator.next();
           JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(key);
           for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
               JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
               String value1 = object.getString("key1");
               String value2 = object.getString("key2");
            }
        }
    }
 catch (JSONException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you can get name and id from key like this:

```
String str="Mr. VICKRAM SINGH_269";
String array[]=  str.split("_");
String name =array[0];
String id =array[1];
```

Comment: JSON Array is Dynamic...it change time to time.. All JSON Array is store in JSON object  from which I have to fetch

Comment: post your json Response

Comment: @RishabhSaxena see my edited code

Comment: I think this helps @RishabhSaxena you can get your key here String key =  iterator.next();

Comment: Thank you I find My solution.....I also Want to remove Digits in Student name please help me

Comment: @RishabhSaxena  see my updated answer fro your name and digit  problem. pass  key of array in place of str

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Write the name of your array here");
```

and then loop your jsonArray Object

Comment: array is dynamic...I dont know the name of an array

Comment: post your JSON @RishabhSaxena

Comment: {"key":["item","item2","item3"]} you should have a key for your array in json string, as it is 'key' here. otherwise, your json is not a valid json. Could you please post your json string?

Comment: {"Mr. VICKRAM SINGH_269":[{"status":"P","date":"2017-02-05"},{"status":"P"‌​,"date":"2017-02-06"‌​}],"Mr. VIVEK KUMAR YADAV_276":[{"status":"P","date":"2017-02-05"},{"status":"P"‌​,"date":"2017-02-06"‌​}]}         Array is Dynamic so we cannot fetch using name of it